# Ibm mobile first: Is there a way to send events even though app is killed

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, background-process

I am building an Application using Ibm Mobile First. In which I need to sync-up some data with server whenever the device gets the Internet connection.

To achieve this I have implemented a broadCast receiver in Android Native.

```
public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    boolean isConnected = BasicUtils.isConnected(context);

    L.e("onReceive :  "+isConnected);

    Config.isConnected = isConnected;

    try {
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

        data.put("isConnected", isConnected);

        WL.getInstance().sendActionToJS("isConnected", data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }


    }
}
```

I am using this method WL.getInstance().sendActionToJS("isConnected", data) to send Data to Js which is working fine when app is running but **not working when the app is killed**.

So is there a way I can send some event from Android native to js when the app is killed or not running?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is rubbing the mobile first SDK as a Service in Android.

Unfortunately at this time the SDK is not available for a Service in Android.